# Trying to get Pascal to read from file then add all of the even numbers having issues.

Tags: loops, for-loop, pascal

OK so I am trying to get Pascal to read a set of integers from a input file then take the even numbers and add them together with in the range of 1-50.  Not working for me.  Here is what I have:
List of input file numbers
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 64 13 14 15 16 71 33 34 35 36 41 44 46 82 512 49 50
And my pascal program:

```
program even(input,output,indata); 
uses crt;
Var
  indata:text;
  num, even:integer;
begin
  clrscr;
  assign(indata, 'j:\num.txt');
  reset(indata)0;
  read(indata, num);
  while num>50 do
  begin
         read(indata, num);
         if num mod 2=0 then
         even:=even+num;
  end;
  writeln('Even sum is', even);
  readln( );
end.
```

Any help would be great!  When I run it I get text as "Even sum is 0".

Comment: And always, always, mention your compiler and version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first fix your code so it will even compile. The line that calls `reset` has the `0` after the closing `)`, which is invalid syntax.

You need to first initialize your `even` variable, so that it contains a valid starting point.

Next, you need to fix the logic in your `while` loop. It's backwards. :-) You need to test for `num < 50` if you want to stop at the end - the test you have now for `num > 50` means that the loop will never execute, because the first value (`1`) ends the `while` loop.

This works in a plain console application in Delphi.

```
program Project2;

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  InData: Text;
  num, even: Integer;

begin
  AssignFile(InData, 'D:\TempFiles\numbers.txt');
  reset(indata);
  read(indata, num);
  even := 0;
  while num < 50 do
  begin
    read(indata, num);
    if num mod 2 = 0 then
       even := even + num;
  end;
  writeln('Even sum is ', even);
  readln;
end.
```

It produces the output (which is correct according to the way your code is written, because it reads the value `64` inside the `while num` loop and therefore executes 1 time more than it should, and `64` is even so it gets added to `even` - I'll leave that for you to figure out). :-)

```
Even sum is 96.
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done Pascal in a few decades, but if I recall:

You're saying:

```
while num > 50 do
```

and your first number is 1, so it just skips the loop and prints the initial value of 'even', which is 0.

You may have meant:

```
while num < 50 do
```

but even that will just exit at the first value 50 or greater.

If you mean to read all the numbers, but filter out those greater than 50, I think it's more like:

```
program even(input,output,indata); 
uses crt;
Var
  indata:text;
  num, even:integer;
begin
  clrscr;
  assign(indata, 'j:\num.txt');
  reset(indata)0;  

  (* read all of the numbers *)
  while not eof(indata) do
  begin
         read(indata, num);

         (* skip those greater than 50 *)
         if num <= 50
         begin
             if num mod 2=0 then
             even:=even+num;
         end;
  end;
  writeln('Even sum is', even);
  readln( );
end.
```

Comment: @KenWhite how do you fix that?  Thanks for your input.

Comment: thanks but doesn't compile may be do too the error that Ken said.

Answer (score 0):

The previous posters have given good advice but I would add at the end (before `end.`)

`CloseFile(infile)` or `Close(infile)`

(depending on your version of Pascal). This will probably not affect the program output but is a good habit to get into for the future - if you're writing to (rather than reading from) a text file and don't close it, you may find some text is missing, or the file becomes unreadable.